# Are the tangent lines at the farthest-separated points on a closed plane curve always parallel?

Tags: plane-geometry, tangent-line, plane-curves

Suppose you have a closed differentiable plane curve. Are the tangent lines to the curve at the most distant points on the curve always parallel? What if we assume that the curve is convex?

I don't see why this should be the case, but it also seems like it might be the kind of weird geometric property that unexpectedly turns out to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be our closed differentiable planar curve with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x_0$. We wish to find the $s<t$ such that
$$F(s,t) := \|\gamma(s) - \gamma(t)\|^2$$
is maximized.
Take the derivative with respect to $s$ and $t$: we find that
$$\nabla F(s,t) = 2\bigg( (\gamma(s) - \gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(s), (\gamma(s) - \gamma(t))\cdot -\gamma'(t)\bigg).$$
At an extremal point, the gradient must be 0: this happens when $s = t$, or at points $s < t$ where $\gamma(s), \gamma(t)$ are farthest away from each other (locally.)

The gradient implies that both $\gamma'(s), \gamma'(t)$ are orthogonal to the vector $\gamma(s) - \gamma(t)$: in $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is exactly what you wanted to prove, because the orthogonal complement of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is one dimensional. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ or greater, however, we don't have such a guarantee.